# Delete Rows with Duplicate Column Data in Specific Columns

Tags: sql

I have a table we'll call Table1 with a bunch of junk data in it and no unique identifier column.

I want to select some columns from Table1 and transfer the data to Table2. However, after the transfer, I need to delete rows from Table2 with duplicates in 3 of the columns.

Let's say I have a row in Table2 with columns `[FirstName]`, `[LastName]`, `[CompanyName]`, `[City]`, and `[State]` that were transferred. I want only the rows with unique combinations of `[FirstName]`, `[LastName]`, and `[CompanyName]` to remain. To add to the confusion, `[LastName]` and/or `[CompanyName]` could contain NULL values. How could I accomplish this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT [FirstName],[LastName],['CompanyName'] FROM [Table]` Hav u tried this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unique entries can be created using the `distinct` keyword.

```
select distinct 
       FirstName, 
       LastName, 
       CompanyName 
  from MyTable
```

So if you issue the following command, you will only add distinct values to the new table

```
insert into newTable
(
       FirstName, 
       LastName, 
       CompanyName 
)
select distinct 
       FirstName, 
       LastName, 
       CompanyName 
  from MyTable
 where not exists (
   select 1 from newTable 
    where newTable.FirstName   = MyTable.FirstName
      and newTable.LastName    = MyTable.LastName
      and newTable.CompanyName = MyTable.CompanyName
  )
```

Another nice way to add distinct new values to a table can be done by using the 'MERGE' command.

```
merge newtable as target
using (select distinct 
              FirstName, 
              LastName, 
              CompanyName 
         from MyTable
       ) as source
   on target.FirstName   = target.FirstName
  and target.LastName    = target.LastName
  and target.CompanyName = target.CompanyName

when not matched by target then
  insert (FirstName, 
          LastName, 
          CompanyName)
  values (target.FirstName, 
          target.LastName, 
          target.CompanyName);
```

The  `MERGE` command gives you the option to control when you want to synchronize tables.

Answer (score 0):

see here example , might be this is what you wanted..[link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ff71/1/0)

```
insert into Table2(`firstname` , `lastname` , `companyname`)
select a.firstname,a.lastname,a.companyname 
from 
(select distinct(concat(firstname,',',lastname,',',companyname))
,firstname,lastname,companyname from Table1) a;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table t2
as
select distinct FirstName,LastName,CompanyName,City,State from t1;

with the below query u 'll get to know we have duplicate entries or not.
select FirstName,LastName,CompanyName,count(*) from t2
group by FirstName,LastName,CompanyName
having Count(*) >1;

delete from t2 a where rowid not in (select min(rowid) from t2 b where a.column1=b.column1 
and .....);
```